# AWS CodeBuild fails in DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase using CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF

Tags: aws-codebuild

If I check the 'Build phase' tab of a CodeBuild project called from CodePipeline using CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF, I get the following error:

> Internal Service Error: CodeBuild is experiencing issues

[image: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Internal Service Error: CodeBuild is experiencing issues]

Answer (score 0):

AWS support responded that this can be caused by having too many 'git refs' in the repo. At the time of this writing, CodeBuild uses a go-lang -based library for handling git and the library has a known limitation.

AWS support recommended switching to the CODE_ZIP method of passing code between the CodePipeline 'source' stage and the CodeBuild stage at issue.

We might also try to reduce the number of refs in the repo.